# Report Viewer Expression, How to check if the value is DateTime or double?

Tags: expression, rdlc, reportviewer, iif

I need some help in my Report Viewer Expression.
I'm in this certain situation which I don't know the data type of my value, since the user select it from another place.
but I need to know, if the value is DateTime, or it is Double. and I want to write LongDateFormat if it is DateTime, and 4 decimals if it is double.
I'm writing this Expression, and it results me as #Error instead of my values in my Tablix.

`iif(
    IsDate(Fields(First(Fields!Value.Value,"DataSet1")).Value)
    ,DateValue(Fields(First(Fields!Value.Value,"DataSet1")).Value).ToLongDateString()
    ,Round(Fields(First(Fields!Value.Value,"DataSet1")).Value,4)
    )`

Although when im using the only if without the needed information, I will get the results without the #Error.

Answer (score 0):

Using `IIf` you have to remember that both side (`TruePart` and `FalsePart`) are always evaluated so rounding a date or formatting a double as a long date raise an #Error.

You can use custom code (right click design surface outside report > `Report Properties > Code`) and replace `IIf` with an `If/Then/Else`:

```
Public Function strFormatValue(objValue As Object) As String

    If IsDate(objValue) Then
        strFormatValue = CDate(objValue).ToLongDateString
    Else
        strFormatValue = Format(Round(CDbl(objValue), 4), "f4").ToString
    End If

End Function
```

And call it from your `Tablix` with an expression like this:

```
=Code.strFormatValue(Fields!Value1.Value)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I couldnt do it without your help